# 2-Methylpropan-2-ol and Iodoform test

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, organic-oxidation

Can 2-methylpropan-2-ol be converted into methyl ketone the action of $\ce{I2}$ in the presence of alkali base and thus give iodoform test?

Answer given to this question is that it can't give iodoform test. Please could someone confirm this with an explaination.

Comment: $\ce{C^2}$ of "2-methylpropan-2-one" will be pentavalent...

Comment: No it cannot. 2-methyl-propan-2-ol cannot be oxidised further and no rearrangement is likely to occur to give a methyl ketone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, 2-methylpropan-2-ol cannot give iodoform test, as it cannot be converted into a methyl ketone.

Generally, alpha hydroxy methyl type (*this is not the actual nomenclature*) groups can give iodoform on oxidation.